# How to correctly point a subdomain to my local server?

Tags: dns, subdomain

I have been using No-IP.com's free service and a subdomain they provided to access my local server, which is on my computer. I use EasyPHP devserver as my local server.

In order to not continue to rely on No-IP.com's service, I added an A Record to my own domain name (xxxxxxx.dev) and pointed the newly created subdomain (xxx.xxxxxxx.dev) to my IP address. However, it is not working.

As the time of writing this question, I have tested accessing my local server with my IP address and the subdomain provided by No-IP.com, and both works. It's just my own subdomain (xxx.xxxxxxx.dev) that isn't working, and my browser's error message says it can't establish a connection to the server at xxx.xxxxxxx.dev.

What am I doing wrong?

Some culprits I'm suspecting are:

- SSL issue. Browsers automatically change the connection to a .dev domain to a secured connection. But my browser's error message does not seem to suggest a SSL issue.
- Anti-virus software issue. Not sure how to check if it is related. But I don't see my anti-virus showing any warning.

**EDIT**: It has been more than 48 hours since I added the A Record.

Comment: Can it be a propagation delay?

Comment: @Kannan Thanks. It has been more than 48 hours so I guess it probably is not a propagation delay. Sorry for not mentioning this in my question. I had updated my question.

Comment: have you checked at intodns.com?

Comment: @Steve Thanks for letting me know the tool. I just tried it, and the result said: "Can't get nameservers at parent server!<br>I only check domains not subdomains!"

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Try https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx and choose DNS lookup from the drop down to the right of the text field

Comment: @Steve That one worked. On the result page, it showed my subdomain and the IP address the subdomain points to. On the same page, it also showed a green checkmark followed by a "Test" column whose value is "DNS Record Published" and a "Result" column whose value is "DNS Record found".

Comment: The only other things I wonder are a) do you have the right IP address and b) is a firewall blocking it

Comment: Is your server configured to accept requests to `xxx.xxxxxxx.dev`? (Although if you can access your server by the IP alone then it would seem to suggest that all requests for that IP are routed to your site? Although, if it's not then you would also get the browser "connection" error you've stated.)

Comment: @Steve a) Yes. I can access my local server with the IP address and my subdomain is pointing to that IP address and b) I tried disabling my Windows' and my anti-virus software's firewalls, and the issue persists.

Comment: @MrWhite Could you please explain how to check that? I don't remember configuring anything for No-IP.com's subdomain, and its subdomain somehow just works.

Comment: I think @MrWhite is asking whether at your server you have added the domain into the server configuration.

Comment: @Steve Thanks. In my apache folder, there is a file called "http.conf". That is the only file I can think of when it comes to configuring acceptable IP addresses and/or ports. But I don't know whether or where I can add subdomains into my server configuration. I didn't do anything like adding No-IP.com's subdomain into my server configuration, and the No-IP.com's subdomain just works without problems.

Comment: "SSL issue. ... But my browser's error message does not seem to suggest a SSL issue." - Is your server _listening_ on port 443? Are you able to "connect" over HTTPS via the IP address or No-IP subdomain? If your server is not listening on port 443 then you will get a "connection" error, not an _SSL error_ as such (although this is still arguably an "SSL issue").

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks for letting me know that. I just had my server listened on port 443, and the error messages have changed. Now some parts of the error messages are "**This site can’t provide a secure connection**: xxx.xxxxxxx.dev sent an invalid response." (Google Chrome) and "**Secure Connection Failed**: An error occurred during a connection to xxx.xxxxxxx.dev. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length." (Mozilla Firefox)

Comment: According to my researches, it seems that I'll have to do some configuration to my local server so that it can generate a SSL certificate and achieve the result I want. I think that's too much of a hassle. I decided to register a new domain name on a domain extension which does not require SSL. Thanks for your helps.